# ASP.NET Core: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, iis

I am trying to deploy my Angular and .Net Core app using IIS but I get the following error message

> The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page
> '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware
> handled the request. Your application is running in Production mode,
> so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA
> manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development
> environment.

This is what my startup.cs looks like

> namespace GammaFramework {
> public class Startup  {       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)        {           Configuration = configuration;      }
>
> ```
>   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
>
>   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add
> ```
>
> services to the container.        public void
> ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)        {
> services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
>
> ```
>         services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
>
>         //services.AddDbContext<GammaFrameworkContext>(options =>
>         //  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("GammaFrameworkContext")));
>
>         services.AddDbContext<GammaFrameworkContext>();
>
>         services.AddCors(options =>
>         {
>             options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
>                 builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod()
>                     .AllowAnyHeader()
>                     .AllowCredentials());
>         });
>
>         services.AddScoped(typeof(IDataRepository<>), typeof(DataRepository<>));
>
>         // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
>         services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
>         {
>             configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
>         });
>
>         services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
>         {
>             options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
>         });
>     }
>
>   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to
> ```
>
> configure the HTTP request pipeline.      public void
> Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)       {           if
> (env.IsDevelopment())             {
> app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();            }           else            {
> // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
> app.UseHsts();          }
>
> ```
>         app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
>         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
>         app.UseStaticFiles();
>         app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
>
>         app.UseMvc(routes =>
>         {
>             routes.MapRoute(
>                 name: "default",
>                 template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
>         });
>
>         app.UseSpa(spa =>
>         {
>             // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
>             // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
>
>             spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
>
>             if (env.IsDevelopment())
>             {
>                 spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
>             }
>         });
>     }     } }
> ```

inside my wwwroot folder I have:
api folder: webapi project
app folder: build angular folder
web.config: copied from webapi project

Comment: How did you deploy your application? Did you check the console for any other error messages? Does it work fine locally?

Comment: I published it via Visual Studio. Yes it does work locally if I launch the .exe and then browse to the endpoint but I need to get it working on the IIS

Comment: Besides these, do you have any other error messages?

Comment: I seem to be having this error as well, did you find a solution?

Comment: I meet the same error. did you found a solution?